# Error importing file 'd:\KR\ChartEngine\obj\Debug\ChartEngine.dll' -- An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to compile a VS2013 project with Visual Studio 2022. I installed VS2022 and made the initial configurations of the project as I did in VS2013. Then I updated all the packages to their latest versions through NugetPackage Manager. Initially, it had lots of Errors but after updating the packages, all is gone except one which is:
[Error importing file 'd:\KR\ChartEngine\obj\Debug\ChartEngine.dll' -- An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyTAA.jpg)

I installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable x86 and x64 but didn't work. Also, I tried to debug the project in AnyCPU, x86, and x64 modes according to some responses found in StackOverflow. Unfortunately, none of them worked for me. What else can I do?

My System Information:
Windows 10 Home x64 bit.
ChartEngine.dll is x32 bit.